# Keep the correct Selected option value in the edit form

Tags: laravel-8

I have an edit form as follows

```
   <select name="department_id" id="department" class="form-control">
        <option value="" selected disabled>{{ __('Select one') }}</option>
                                                    
           @foreach($departments as $key => $department)
           <option value="{{ $department['id'] }}" {{  $department['department'] == $department['department'] ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $department['department'] }}</option>                                          
           @endforeach
                                                        
    </select>
```

User Model

```
 public function department()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
   }
```

Department Model

```
  public function employees()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

Edit Methods

public function edit($id) {

```
$employee = User::find($id)->toArray();
$designations = Designation::where('deletion_status', 0)
    ->where('publication_status', 1)
    ->orderBy('designation', 'ASC')
    ->select('id', 'designation')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

    $departments = Department::where('deletion_status', 0)
    ->where('publication_status', 1)
    ->orderBy('department', 'ASC')
    ->select('id', 'department')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

return view('pdd.employee.edit', compact('employee','designations','departments'));
```

}

My problem I could not get the selected value shown. Could anyone help

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

User has one department

Department has many Users

Users in this case are employees

```
 <select name="department_id" id="department" class="form-control">
      <option value="" selected disabled>{{ __('Select one') }}</option>
         @foreach($departments as  $department)
         <option value="{{ $department['id'] }}" {{  $department['id'] == $employee['department_id'] ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $department['department'] }}</option>  
         @endforeach
 </select>
```